# Appending data to XML. Trouble with writing to document: not appending nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have created a simple solution that should append some written data into an XML file.

When the user enters the info into a room, and clicks 'add room', it should write that information to the XML file, however it is not working.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Room r = new Room();
        r.RoomName = txtRoomName.Text;
        r.Length = numLength.Text;
        r.Width = numWidth.Text;
        r.TotalArea = txtArea.Text;
        r.Quality = comboQuality.Text;
        r.RoomPrice = txtRoomPrice.Text;
        //Once these are set, we need to add this info to the Room List.
        rooms.Add(r);
        listView1.Items.Add(r.RoomName);

        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        xDoc.Load(path + "\\info.xml");
        XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("rooms");

        foreach (Room x in rooms)
        {
            XmlNode xHeader = xDoc.CreateElement("Room_Name");
            XmlNode xLength = xDoc.CreateElement("Length");
            XmlNode xWidth = xDoc.CreateElement("Width");
            XmlNode xArea = xDoc.CreateElement("Area");
            XmlNode xQuality = xDoc.CreateElement("Quality");
            XmlNode xRoomPrice = xDoc.CreateElement("Room_Price");
            xHeader.InnerText = r.RoomName;
            xLength.InnerText = r.Length;
            xWidth.InnerText = r.Width;
            xArea.InnerText = r.TotalArea;
            xQuality.InnerText = r.Quality;
            xRoomPrice.InnerText = r.RoomPrice;
            xDoc.Save(path + "\\Address Book - User\\info.xml");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to isolate your problem to the part where you think it is misbehaving or acting differently then you would expect. Then post that relevant code snippet here and describe your problem.

Comment: If there is an error, post it to your original question please.  Also, please post a condensed version of the `XmlNode` "Rooms".

Comment: Does it still happen if you don't assign Quality? Does it still cause trouble if you do it without the for loop? That's how to narrow the problem... Show us the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating XmlNodes, but not appending it anywhere. Use `AppendChild()` to add the elements somewhere (potentially `xNode`).

It also seems that you want an element `<Room>` to which you append the name, size and other properties.